# Describe the image of the lines given by the vectors $e_1$, $e_2$, $e_3$ under $A^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the matrix
$A=$
$
\begin{bmatrix} 
1&2&3&4\\
5&6&11&17\\
19&20&21&22\\
0&0&2&2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$
describe the image of the lines given by the vectors $e_1, e_2, e_3$ under $A^n$.

I think I figured it out actually. For this problem, the particular eigenvectors and eigenvalues are extremely ugly. A more general approach, though, would be to simply solve for these eigenvectors and then use them to describe the line (since under the $A^n$-th transformation these eigenvectors will only be affected by scaling). So, for the line $l_1=(k,0,0,0)^T$ for some arbitrary k in $R$, you would solve it so that $A^n(l_1)=kA^n(e_1)=k(\lambda_1^na_1v_1+...+\lambda_j^na_jv_j)$ where j is the amount of eigenvectors you have for your transformation and $a_j$ represents some scalar. You could solve it for the case n=0 to get your $a_j$'s and then you'd have the general image for the lines under the transformations.

This could be potentially wrong, as I have no official answer for this, but when I tested it on a few smaller matrices it seemed to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since:
$
e_1=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}^T
$
The line given by them is:
$
l_1=\{\begin{pmatrix}\lambda&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}^T|\lambda\in\mathbb{K}\}
$
Then:
$$
(Al_1)^T=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda  & 5 \lambda  & 19 \lambda  & 0 \\\end{pmatrix}^T
$$
$$
(Al_2)^T=\begin{pmatrix}2\lambda  & 6 \lambda  & 20 \lambda  & 0 \\\end{pmatrix}^T
$$
$$
(Al_3)^T=\begin{pmatrix}3 \lambda  & 11 \lambda  & 21 \lambda  & 2 \lambda  \\\end{pmatrix}^T
$$
Just the columns of $A$ multiplied by some constant.

Comment: Doesn't this only apply for the first transformation?